# Deleting an infinite list in Haskell

Tags: list, shell, haskell

I've just started using Haskell. I read that we can generate the infinite list of positive natural numbers with [0..], and tried it out.

However, now I can't get back to the start of my file. I have deleted many of the numbers, but how can I get rid of this infinite list of numbers?

Comment: What do you mean? You can not delete numbers from the infinite list. Data is immutable in Haskell...

Comment: I do not understand your question, can you please schow yuor code?

Comment: I have typed [0..]. How can I delete all the numbers generated by typing [0..]?

Comment: There is an infinite list of numbers on my page. I can't GET to the code at the beginning of my file. That is precisely my problem.

Comment: Basically, how can I 'undo' the operation of [0..]

Comment: Well how can I go back to the start of my file, then?

Comment: @Lukelindenbaum: but `ghci` is simply an interactive shell that prints to the stdout... It depends on your terminal configuration how much you can scroll back... You can however use the arrow keys to move through your history.

Comment: The arrow won't get back quickly to the beginning of my file because there are so many numbers on the page.

Comment: @Lukelindenbaum do `ctrl + c` to stop printing infinite list of numbers

Comment: I've already interrupted the printing of the list. However I cannot get back to the beginning of my file before the numbers started. I'm sure it is a trivial problem, I just don't know how to get there.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your code or the state of the program.

Comment: What does it have to do with then? How can I get to the beginning of the file?

Comment: @Lukelindenbaum: this is not a file, but a shell. A shell prints to the stdout. A *terminal* is a program that handles that input/output and displays it on the screen. Some terminals allow an arbitrary amount of lines to be stored, others don't in that case the lines will be lost once too much output is generated. This has nothing to do with Haskell or ghci, it is simply how a terminal works.

Comment: `ctrl-d` then `alt-f4`

Comment: Thanks. How can I get to the beginning of the shell, then? Or whatever term  is appropriate here

Comment: FANTASTIC! That works.

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to Haskell and GHCi, and has more to do with how an OS shell works. When you executed printing of an infinite list, you instructed the computer to keep putting more bytes into the screen buffer. Those have limited capacity and will eventually lose the data put in there by previous commands.

To avoid those kinds of situations in the future, redirect the output from a command to a text file, and run your code from a saved file and not GHCi as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I don't possess the basic knowledge of certain terms in your answer that would enable me to understand it, but perhaps that will change as things proceed. :)

Comment: Trying to write an infinite string to a file isn't exactly a fruitful activity either... sure, after the process dies you'll retain all the input from the beginning, but the file will likely be several GB in size, and most text editors will just choke on it. When you know a list is infinite, a better way to examine it is to `take` some prefix of the list (e.g. `take 10 [0..]`).

Comment: @user2407038 Sure, my suggestion was more about unknown size of the output and how to protect yourself against it. If you write such a file, you can then safely examine its size and discard its contents if you realize your program fell into an infinite loop. There are also numerous tool that can read such files chunk by chunk without loading them whole into memory.